# How to create executable Python code on Intel Edison?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, yocto, intel-edison

I'm beginner with Intel Edison and Linux, all I know that the OS is Yocto.
I wrote a code written in Python on windows, that code work on windows without any problem, it import an image, apply some effects and give a result as a number.
My problem is I don't know where can I put the image, I created a file in Edison drive called "image" and I put the image inside but I don't know how to read that file and execute my code from Putty.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. First, create a Pyhton file by using nano which it's built in Yocto. After that, I used WinSCP to explorer my Intel Edison files. Then, I just dragged and dropped the images in the same directory of my Python file. Finally, by using Putty I executed my Python code by this command: python image.py, "image,py" is the file name that I already created it by Nano.